# Найти среднее в промежутке

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Помогите пожалуйста найти среднее количество фильмов в год, выпущенных в XX веке, и, выпущенных в XXI веке.
Я написал

```html
SELECT production_year,COUNT(*) as average,
CASE
    when production_year >= 1900 and production_year < 2001 then 'XX'
    when production_year >= 2001 and production_year < 2100 then 'XXI'
END AS century
FROM title
where kind_id=1 and production_year between 1901 and 2100
GROUP by production_year
```

[image: Вывод]

Мне нужно найти среднее `average` с 1901 по 2000 и с 2001 по 2100

Comment: Я по колхозному сам сделал так. Взял свой запрос в подзапрос, а перед ним написал `SELECT AVG(average), 'XX' FROM (Мой запрос) WHERE century='XX'` и через `UNION` такой же запрос только с XXI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы почти успели. Добавляем аггрегацию на Ваш запрос:

```sql
SELECT t.century, sum(t.average)/count(*) as average
  FROM (<Ваш запрос здесь>) t
 GROUP BY t.century;
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- MySQL code

SELECT (production_year + 99) DIV 100 century,
       COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT production_year) AS average
FROM title
-- where kind_id=1 and production_year between 1901 and 2100
GROUP BY century
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!